# Is there any function in PHP to compress image to desired size(in KB) or to the nearest size defined

Tags: php, image, compression, imagick, php-gd

I have a 500 kb image and I wanna compress it using PHP GD or Imagick library. But I didn't found any function or method to compress the image to the desired size (150 KB).
The function should try to compress the size to 150 kB or nearest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56362422/231316

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Compress Image to Meet File Size Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872013/php-compress-image-to-meet-file-size-limit)

Comment: Yes. But I was looking for something else.